# appFailedToResumeInTime crash

Tags: iphone, crash

when i am testing my application on iphone 3g and ios 4.2.6 my app is getting blank screen some times when i launch the app after quitting that .and applicationwillenterforeground method is called .at that time can any one explain me how to sort out this

and when i am running the application in 4 it is working fine but if i run my application in 3g . my app is getting crashed some times saying appFailedToResumeInTime .. even though i moved out all the connectivity process from appdelegate method

Answer (score 0):

Try hard resetting the device, press and hold the sleep and home buttons until the device turns off itself. **No data** from your device will be lost during this process.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are taking too long to resume and the OS is terminating your app (I think you have about 10 secs to launch).  I would guess that on the newer hardware it is happening a quicker and just beating the OS.

Look into optimising your start up/resume code.

Comment: My code is working fine iphone 4 . if i run the same application iphone 3g ios 4.2 app launch is ok but if i quit the application and run the application instantly for same time . the app is getting crashed atter calling the applicationWillEnterForeGround method.any help on this issue .

Comment: Hi Naren, think you will need to post some of your code to be able to help you further.

Comment: - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    isCountrySelected=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"isCountrySelected"];

Comment: if( !isCountrySelected || [isCountrySelected isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || [isCountrySelected isEqualToString:@""] )
    {
        appMode = kAppModeCountrySelected ;
        
        
    }
NSString* rememberMe = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"rememberMe"];
 if(rememberMe && [rememberMe isEqual:@"1"]) {